# TypeScript Error on ServiceWorker code: [2345] [object Object]

Tags: typescript, service-worker

I'm writing a service-worker `activate` event handler in TypeScript (2.4.2) that looks like:

```
function activate(event: ExtendableEvent) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames: Array<string>) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName: string) {
          if (!OFFLINE_CACHE_REGEX.test(cacheName)) {
            return;
          }
          if (OFFLINE_CACHE_NAME !== cacheName) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

The approach is inspired from Jake Archibald's [offline cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook).

The problem is, TypeScript compiler throws an error and all that says is this:

> ../path-to-file.ts:40: **[2345] [object Object]**'

where line #40 in the above code point to `return Promise.all(`

While I can guess the error code is TS2345, I can't really make any heads or tails of what this means since all I have is an `[object Object]`.

Any pointers would greatly help!

Comment: Are you sure that your cacheNames array is an array and not an object?

Comment: Was my first instinct as well. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys) says it should indeed be an array. Also a quick check on `cacheNames instanceof Array`returns `true`. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the type of the cacheNames array, since you omit a return value in the first if statement. That returns undefined, so your array doesn't consist solely of strings anymore. Change the return value to cacheName or an empty string and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured that out a moment back, and modified my code to use a combo of `filter` and `map` to remove the undefined items and get rid of the error.

Comment: Ah, also a great solution. Glad it's sorted now! :)